SQL Server performance optimize bulk copy large volume of data using powershell
We receive daily SQL Server database backups from a third-party vendor that we restore. After the database is online we use bcp to export all of the tables data as .csv files for other applications and vendors to consume this data. The problem I run into is when the database size is small ~ 20 GB it works alright but when the data volume is large > 50 GB everything slows down. These are nightly jobs and sometimes even after 10 hours I see the process in a hanged state with partial data in the storage. Are there any other options to performance optimize powershell script.
Powershell:
$connString = "Server=$serverName;Database=$databaseName;Integrated Security=True;TrustServerCertificate=True"
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($connString)
$conn.Open()

$tables = Get-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance $serverName | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq $databaseName} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Tables

foreach ($table in $tables) {
    $tableName = $table.Name
    $filePath = Join-Path $outputPath "$tableName.csv"

    $columns = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -Query "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$tableName'" -TrustServerCertificate
    $headerRow = $columns.COLUMN_NAME -join ","

    $query = "SELECT * FROM [$databaseName].dbo.[$tableName]"
    $data = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -Query $query -TrustServerCertificate

    $header = $headerRow | Out-File -FilePath $filePath -Encoding UTF8 -Append

    $data | Export-Csv -Path $filePath -NoTypeInformation -Append -Encoding UTF8

    Write-Host "Exported $tableName to $filePath"
}

$conn.Close()


Why export all the data to .csv files? Might be better to have downstream applications connect to the database directly for only the data they need? Do vendors need all the tables in the database?

Powershell is a red herring, it just calls bcp which cannot be beaten for export me thinks. Sounds like you need to rethink your approach. Can files be appended somehow? Perhaps you can use multithreaded export, might go a bit faster

If you need to transfer data SSIS/Integration Services Packages are perfect for data flow from one source to another and have built in performance options.

Add more memory to the machine.  You must be using swap space.  Did you try Invoke-SQLCMD? The export using Export-CSV.  Another choice is to use the utility sqlcmd.exe which is designed to handle large files.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd/sqlcmd-utility?view=sql-server-ver16&tabs=go%2Cwindows&pivots=cs1-bash  Use the -s option to specify the column separator and -o to specify the output file

Aside... hopefully your source data doesn't contain any quotes ("), commas (,) or line break characters because bcp is just awful at handling those.

Do you have to perform the exports serially? Sounds like you could use Start-Jobfor each table to start a parallel process that exports that table's contents, then just wait for all of the jobs to complete. PowerShell's Export-Csv cmdlet, when used with something like Invoke-Sqlcmd, will give you much more RFC-compliant files than bcp ever would.

I updated the OP with Invoke-Sqlcmd. Due to some constraints we are to stick with either Powershell or T-SQL. I can load each table data concurrently doesn't have to be in a serial manner. I'll try Start-Job and Export-Csv cmdlet.
